# Question about flow

Tags: vector-fields

Could anyone explain to me how to get to equation 1.15 from 1.14?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just expresses the fact that, for differentiable $f$, 
$$f(t) = f(0) + tf^\prime(0) + \cal{O} (t^2)$$
(think of $\sigma_t(p)$ as a function of $t$).